# Where i need to change the format of date and currency for german locale

Tags: user, language, locale, format

I have created one `quote` (standard object) and that quote has product unitPrice and created date

I am playing with that quote with two different users 1. BOB and 2. Alice (both have same role and same profile) only Locale is different, BOB has United states and Alice has German

The problem is when i login with BOB i see UnitPrice `2,045`(this is perfect) and when i login with Alice i see UnitPrice `2.045`(this is incorrect)

I have searched and finally i found the below link to change the locale setting but not sure why i am not able to find and change the currency and date format

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_supported_locales.htm&type=0

Comment: your org must multi currency enabled. and locale is only responsible for language and date format if I'm not wrong. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_enable_multicurrency.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Comment: @blackPerlSAF thanks for reply i tried it by disabling the multi currency but still i am not getting the actual output, `comma` replaced with `dot`

Comment: I said to enable and check values quoted for EURO (conversion rate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2.045 is actually the correct format for the German locale. Much of Europe (and much of the rest of the world, for that matter) uses the period/full-stop as the digit grouping separator, and a comma as the decimal separator (e.g. 'Two Thousand Forty Five point sixteen' would appear as 2.045,16).

Automatic number and date formatting based on locale is pretty deeply baked into Salesforce, and you'll be hard pressed to change it.

The only way I know of to override this is using visualforce and [`<apex:outputText>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm)

The currency formatting example from that page:

> ```
> <!-- For this example to render properly, you must associate the Visualforce page
> with a valid account record in the URL.
> For example, if 001D000000IeChM is the account ID, the resulting URL should be:
> https://Salesforce_instance/apex/myPage?id=001D000000IeChM
> See the Visualforce Developer's Guide Quick Start Tutorial for more information. -->
>
> <apex:page standardController="Account">
>     It is worth:
>     <apex:outputText value="{0, number, 000,000.00}">
>         <apex:param value="{!Account.AnnualRevenue}" />
>     </apex:outputText>
> </apex:page>
> ```

Comment: hi @DerekF is it applicable only for multi-currency enabled org or all the dev org?

Comment: @blackPerlSAF I don't have experience with multi-currency, but I believe that Numbers and Dates are formatted based on locale (and locale alone). Based on a quick read of some documentation, it doesn't look like multi-currency has any effect whatsoever on how numbers are formatted (except for the currency symbol used).

Comment: @DerekF thank you :)